# Increasing reach of unarmed strikes

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk

Is it possible to increase the reach of a monk's unarmed strikes other than by increasing in size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a variety of feats and items that let you do this.

The [Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat---final) feat lets you increase your reach for 5' during your turn only for a -2 to AC for a round. [Monkey Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/monkey-lunge-combat) stacks on this to remove the AC penalty.

The [Combat Patrol](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-patrol-combat) feat lets you increase your threatened area, which effectively gives you reach for AoOs.

Of course, there are some monk weapons that have reach - not your unarmed strike per se but can be used to deliver ki effects.

Magic item wise, [Pliant Gloves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-pliant) give you 10 rounds of reach a day plus other benefits and are pretty inexpensive. [Longarm Bracers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/longarm-bracers) are an even cheaper and more limited version.

Comment: I assume you're assuming some sort of houserule to avoid Monkey Lunge's silliness of "Use a standard action to give all the attacks during the rest of your turn -- not including AoOs -- extra reach"?

Comment: It's also worth noting that Lunge/Monkey Lunge only apply during your turn, not for Threatening opponents during their turns.

Comment: Right, in fact it was noted already. ("...during your turn only...")

Answer (score 7):

You can use the feat [Lunge (Core Rulebook)](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#_lunge).

The only problem is that you need BAB 6 or higher, and it only applies during your turn.

Answer (score 2):

It's feat heavy, but if you happen to have [snake style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/snake-style-combat-style), then [sword masters flair - blue scarf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/swordmaster-s-flair) increases reach with piercing weapons.

Add [kata master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/kata-master) to monk build for panache pool and you can use this most encounters.

Answer (score 1):

[Gloves of the Shortened Path](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-the-shortened-path) are the best for this, if you purchase/make enough of them.  They only get one use/day (that use lasts 10 rounds) but they give you the best range possible, unless free action teleportation prior to an attack counts as 'range'.

Admittedly they only double the spaces to which you have reach, but they increase the range at which you can attack and distance at which you can threaten squares considerably, so they are much more effective than a normal doubling of reach.  They also stack with other reach increases so throw on some [Longarm Bracers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/longarm-bracers) and whatever other reach-granting abilities you have and establish massive, undetectable, AoO kill-zones at extreme range.

Answer (score -4):

Also, depending on your DM, you can use the spell Mighty Fist of the Earth if you are dual classed as a druid.

Comment: Can you clarify why this is dependent on the DM?

Comment: This doesn't increase reach, it's just a spell that lets you do one unarmed attack at range (at the cost of a whole spell).

Comment: It's best for answers to be wholly self-contained. If you want to build on an answer, you can comment on it, once you have more reputation.