# Add line in the sand to warpriest spell list?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, pathfinder-society

I am interested in casting [*line in the sand*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/line-in-the-sand/), but the character in question is a warpriest, not a bloodrager, magus, sorcerer, or wizard. I don’t want to multiclass, and in any event would like to use my warpriest caster level as well as Wisdom for the spellcasting ability score. Is there any way I can add this spell to my warpriest spell list?

If it matters, the warpriest is (ideally) a chaotic-neutral devotee of Calistria, and only material legal in Pathfinder Society is allowed. See [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/109349/4563) for more details about the rest of the desired build. The goal is to replace Combat Reflexes with *line in the sand* and then dump Dexterity in favor of either Strength and the Strength blessing, or Wisdom and the Guided Hand feat.

Comment: Must such a method pass muster with the Pathfinder Society?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That is the goal, so yeah, probably shenanigans won’t work. But I am interested in seeing what you had in mind...

Comment: O, it's complete and utter cheese and, really, pretty much theoretical optimization, but can the character make the skill Break the Game — I mean, *Use Magic Device* — into a class skill?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sure, I’m interested in seeing that anyway.

Answer (score 4):

## [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/) on a [*page of spell knowledge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/)

A [*page of spell knowledge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/) "contains the knowledge of a single arcane or divine spell" like the spell [*line in the sand*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/line-in-the-sand/). The page allows "a spontaneous spellcaster [that] has that spell on her class spell list [to] use her spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her spells known."

The skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/) allows the creature to emulate a class feature. By succeeding on a Use Magic Device skill check (DC 21), the creature can emulate, for example, the [sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/) 1 class feature spells, and a typical sorcerer has on her spell list the spell *line in the sand*.

(Because the caster uses the caster's own spell slots to cast the spell provided by the *page*, this GM would rule that the caster uses for any variables like key ability and caster level the class from which the spell slot comes.)

This process enables *any* creature that can expend the appropriate spell slots—including a warpriest—to expend those spell slots to cast the spell granted by the *page*. (Well, *once* anyway. To cast the spell again, another Use Magic Device skill check must be made.)

This player recommends clearing this process with the GM first. If sprung on an unsuspecting GM, the technique may be met with an awkward silence or a cry of *No way!* and see the GM subsequently banning creatures from using the skill Use Magic Device for such purposes.

Comment: @annoyingimp There's, honestly, no *real* way to know absolutely, but since the dude's using his own spell slots—the *page* only granting spell access—, using the key ability for the class providing the spell slots seems reasonable to this GM.

Comment: @annoyingimp For *Line in the Sand*, at least, it seems the distinction is clear: _Against creatures in the area, you can attempt a number of additional attacks of opportunity per round **equal to your spellcasting ability score modifier**_

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 2):

### [Spell Research](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Research-and-Designing-Spells) is exactly for this!

You can use this to create a similar spell, or learn how to twist an arcane spell into a divine nature or visa-versa. This method takes time, but it adds the spell to your spell list permanently. If your character is coming in at a level besides one, where you would have had time to do this out of game, clear it with your DM first. Actually, Its probably a good idea to clear it with your DM before declaring your action in downtime. As it can offset game balance to some extent.

Comment: This answer would be improved if addressed how spell research is handled in PFS. I would *guess* (but haven’t specifically checked) that it isn’t allowed, or is only allowed in very specific circumstances. And ultimately, even for non-PFS play, spell research amounts to “ask the GM for a houserule in your favor,” and so doesn’t *really* make that great an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @KRyan ...except that Spell Research is an actual part of the RAW game.  That means that it's asking for a favorable ruling, rather than a full-on favorable house-rule.  There is a meaningful difference there.

Comment: @BenBarden I disagree. Spell research is little more than some suggestions for how the GM can use rule-0 to change their game. The player gains no agency from them. And again, since this is a PFS environment, without information about how these rules work *in PFS*, this isn’t a very helpful answer.

Comment: While I do agree that without me providing more information about how this works in PFS it is not as helpful, but Ben is right in that it is part of RAW and specifically states the GM determines the balance repercussions of a NEW spell and sets the spell level accordingly (or even as impossible to cast, but wish kinda does anything anyone can think of [subject to dm] so hard to make a spell stronger than that), but taking a spell that exists is not a new spell, and already has a level, components, and cost, and after those are determined the rules are super clear on the rest.

Comment: However it is still a potential alternative to I Can Chan's answer. I have been looking for more information about how this works in PFS but havent found much. Will update when I do.