# Why does the Flickmace from GoG not have any description?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I was introduced to the Gnomish Flickmace, in the thread about [Brigitte's flail](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120892/how-can-brigittes-flail-from-overwatch-be-simulated). As Carcer said [there](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120895/11129), it's listed in the exotic weapons table on [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/), but there is no description of it. So, why does the Flickmace from [GoG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601252234) not have any description?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Carcer reports that the actual description for the item was apparently mistakenly cut from Gnomes of Golarion itself. I searched a bit about this and found that it was not a mistake. They just needed space:

> > Cylerist wrote:
> >
> > The description of teh Flickmace seems to be missing. It sounds like it could be an interesting weapon.
>
> It got cut for space when the body text ran long, but it remains in the table like an evil, gnome ghost. IIRC it was a mace with a built-in spring, allowing you to use an action to change it from a normal mace to a reach weapon.

[Sean K Reynolds, Contributor on Gnomes of Golarion](http://www.seankreynolds.com/store/index.html)

[source](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8dmh/discuss&page=2?Pathfinder-Companion-%20Gnomes-of-Golarion#75)

Thank you @Carcer and @KRyan for your help in the Brigitte thread :)

Answer (score 4):

The actual mechanics for this weapon can be found in the Weapon Master's Handbook as an example of the Weapon Design rules. This book classifies it as belonging to the polearm weapon group, and describes it as a two-handed weapon with the "spring-loaded" ability. The "spring-loaded" feature creates a polearm which can telescope to gain reach, or collapse to attack adjacent squares, both with a swift action.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to note that we're not a forum, and we don't do discussion, so posts should directly answer the question that was asked. In this case the question is why the flickmace has no *description*, not where its *mechanics* can be found